# If a vector $v \in C(A)^\perp$, does that mean $v \in N(A)$ or that $v \in N(A^T)$ and why?

Tags: linear-algebra

...And what is the difference between $N(A)$ and $N(A^T)$? I'm trying to understand the difference between perpendicular projection matrices and the span of the null space of a subspace. Could you please provide an intuitive explanation?

Answer (score 1):

Briefly, say $A$ is $m\times n$. Then $N(A) = \{x\in\Bbb R^n: Ax = 0\}$, so every such $x$ is orthogonal to all the rows of $A$ (and conversely). Similarly, $N(A^\top) = \{y\in\Bbb R^m: A^\top y = 0\}$, so every such $y$ is orthogonal to all the rows of $A^\top$, i.e., all the columns of $A$ (and conversely). [Here I am suggesting you interpret $Ax$ as the vector whose components are the dot products of the rows of $A$ with $x$.]